# Two ListViews in one activity (not showing)

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to show two ListViews, one below the other. The problem is that the first is hidden, or not showed...

How can I do it? ScrollView with a RelativeLayout inside, or LinearLayout? 
Thank you very much!!

Here is my layout code and a screenshot:

[image]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_header_selector"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_solicituds"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator_solicituds"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_solicituds"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#cdd81e"
            android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbarSize="20dip"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_amics"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="#deeb0e"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_amics"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#cdd81e"
            android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
            android:scrollX="0px"
            android:scrollY="0px"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbarSize="20dip"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/empty"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="No friends added yet."
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try without scroll view. There are some issues between scrollview and listview which are not working good. Add 2 LinearLayout or RelativeLayout for each listview. If you do it with linear you could use android:layout_weight="1" to give half of the screen for each ListView.

Comment: scrollview + listview, romain guy is gonna eat you.

Comment: dont use scroll view,Use linear layout for listview and textview and make it layout weight for that as per your requirement.It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

We should not place listview inside scrollview. Infect we should not place any view that scroll inside scroll view. If you do so then your internal scroll will not get focus or it will be hard to scroll.

Comment: I got the issue : you have to use weight in linear layout views to resolve it

example : 
add these properties in listview and other child views of linear layour

 android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"

Answer (score 0):

Try using Relative Layout 
or assign weights to your listviews so that they can takeup the space in linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"

    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue of how to use two listviews in one activity plagued me for longer than I care to admit.  Here's how I finally resolved it.  And it's actually pretty simple.

You need to stick both listviews within a scrollview as it looks like you tried to do.  Now normally when you do this, the listview renders the size of just one row, which scrolls through the list.  This, obviously, is not optimal.  So the solution is to programatically adjust the layout_height of both the listviews, depending on the number of items/rows in your list.  Here is an example of how this would work:

XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_header_selector"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_solicituds"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_solicituds"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

JAVA:

```
ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_listView1);
list1.getLayoutParams().height = ***set the desired height of list1 using an int***;
ListView lsit2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
list2.getLayoutParams().height = ***set the desired height of list2 using an int***;
```

If you really want to get fancy and set the height of the listview dynamically using dp, then you need to convert the pixel size

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int rowHeight = (int) (dp_height_of_your_rows * scale + 0.5);
```

Then instead of plugging in an integer, you would use rowHeight * the numbers of rows in listView.